# PHP array_slice - how get original array without sliced items

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array with say 50 items in it. I then use array_slice to extract 12 items:

```
$extractItems = array_slice($rows,0,12);
```

I then use the $extractItems and this is fine.

The catch is I want to then write the remaining items (eg: $rows - $extractItems) to cache.

When I view $rows I can see array_slice doesn't remove the items. Just copies a section to a new array.

How would I best get a set of the items not 'array_sliced'?

thankyou :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-splice.php) instead. This would remove the first 12 items from `$rows`

```
$extractedItems = array_splice($rows, 0, 12);
// $rows now equals $rows - $extractedItems
```

A quick demo

```
php > $rows = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
php > $extractedItems = array_splice($rows, 0, 2);
php > var_dump($extractedItems, $rows);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(5)
  [3]=>
  int(6)
}
```

Comment: +1. I don't particularly like mutable arrays, but it can sometimes come in handy :)

Comment: @Jack Yeah, I considered that too but it seemed to match the OP's requirements

Answer (score 5):

You can get the rest of the items by slicing from index 12 onwards:

```
array_slice($rows, 12);
```

This is similar to how `substr($str, $index)` works.